# Iterating through groups taking too long to complete

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, timeit

Let me show you my code first

```
df = pd.read_csv('ConcatOwned1_900.csv', sep='\t')
tp = pd.read_csv('AppCrawlerGenres.csv', sep='\t')

df = df.set_index(['UserID','appid']) 

kalipsiG = []
i = 0
print time.ctime()

for user, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):

    list_apps=new_df.index.get_level_values('appid').unique()
    crawl = tp[tp['appid'].isin(list_apps)].sum()

    kalipsi = (crawl != 0).sum() - 1 # (-1) epeidi exei kai to appid mesa

    kalipsiG.append(kalipsi)
    if (i % 1000) == 0 :
        print '\n',time.ctime()
        print i,user,'\n',new_df

    i += 1
```

Well, i have a really big file(df) with Users that contains for each user appids. Information about appid's is found at the other file(tp).

I have achieved my goal which was creating the kalipsiG variable, which counts non numeric values of some variables.

The only problem is that each 1000 Users it takes about 3 seconds to calculate and i have aprox. 220.000 users.

fast math: it takes about 11 minutes is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Just a rough idea that may help: Have you tired moving the `df.groupby(level=0)` into a variable first before the for loop?

Comment: You should eliminate you `i` variable and print statements from your example: they just distract. Also, showing a few rows of relevant data for `df` and `tp` would be very helpful. [ask]